# css:how to centring navigation list when resizing the window in html5

Tags: css, html

Here is my code in css:

```
*
{
    box-sizing:border-box;  
}
div,body,html,h1,nav,article,footer,header{display:block;}
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
#wrapper
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.title p
{
    text-align:center;
    color:  darkgray;
}
img
{
    vertical-align:middle;  
    margin:0;
}
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}
 #fixme
{    
    height : 175px;
    position: relative;
    overflow : hidden;
}
#animate-area 
{ 
    height: 122%;
    width: 2538px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -15px;
    background-image: url('../img/banner.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 30s linear infinite;
}
    /* Put your css in here */
    @keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
 }
#logo img
 {
    position:absolute;  
    z-index:999;
    vertical-align:middle;
 }   
 h1
 {  
    text-align:center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-bottom: inherit;
 }
 .header-pgf
{
    width: 67%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: auto;   
    margin-top:15px;
}
.nav
{       
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b9b9b9), to(#000));
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, red, yellow);
    margin-top:40px;
    height:45px;
}
.nav ul li
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav > ul li:first-child a
{
    background-color:Red;
}
.nav > ul li:first-child a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.nav li:hover a 
{
    background-color: red;
}
.nav li a 
{
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Html5:

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">COMPANY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MARKETS/SOLUTIONS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">PRODUCTS/SERVICES</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BUSINESSES</a></li>
<li><a href="#">INVESTERS</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

My page look like this(when resizing): http://s14.postimg.org/jggi59co1/Untitled_1_copy.png

As i marked in image, the lists are need to place center when resizing window. Can someone help me to fix this,?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to `ul`: `text-align: center`.

Since your `li`s are set  to `display: inline-block`, you should set its direct parent's `text-align` to `center`, which is `ul`

Comment: and i have one more doubt

Comment: Hmm, but the ul is an inline element wich will not adapt to the parents width. So it should not affect the ul childs. That is why I thought he should set the text-align to the nav, since the nav is the next block element in the tree... Why am I wrong?

Comment: I have added list of links in footer, without using nav. so how to centring those list of links when resizing , like my posted question?

Comment: @Noel Widmer. `<ul>` is a block level element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: @sasi. Just the same, set the direct parent of the images to `text-align: center`

Comment: God damit! I just misunderstood a selector. I thought he overwrote ul to be a inline-block...Thanks!

Comment: @jacelysh: If i put text-align:center for parent, it will displayed as center too in normal window. But i need, in normal show left,.. and when resizing show center.

Comment: You should be using media queries. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I am not working with responsive design. i just want to center when resizing.

Comment: You cannot change alignment of elements without using media queries.

Comment: ok @jacelysh: can you show me code for footer-links should show like this http://s14.postimg.org/jggi59co1/Untitled_1_copy.png( i marked at bottom) using nav list?

Answer (score 0):

text-align applies to inline and inline-block **child elements**.
You are trying to set this property **to the element itself**.

Try to set text-align to the nav.

Did that work?